# javascript grade calculating and average

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML code, for some reason this code only takes three values , it doesn't take more than three values, and when I try to enter more, it displayed only the first three values I entered. Something is wrong with my code but I couldn't figure it out. Please help.

```
var gradeCounter, gradeValue, total, average, grade;

total = 2;
gradeCounter = 0;
grade = prompt("enter grade, -1 to Quit:", "0");
gradeValue = parseInt(grade);

while (gradeValue != -1 && gradeValue > 65) document.write("<br>" + gradeValue + " pass</br>");
  total = total + gradeValue;
  gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
  grade = prompt("enter grade, -1 to Quit:", "0");
  gradeValue = parseInt(grade);
}

if (gradeCounter != 0 && gradeValue <= 65) {
    document.write("<br>" + gradeValue + " fail</br>");

    total = total + gradeValue;
    gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
    grade = prompt("enter grade, -1 to Quit:", "0");
    gradeValue = parseInt(grade);
    average = total / gradeCounter;

    document.write("<br>total grade: " + gradeCounter + "</bt>");
    document.write("<br>average passing grade:" + average + "</br>");
} 
else document.write("total grade:" + 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq]. Additionally, read [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use markdown to its full potential. If you show people that you've invested time into asking a decent, well-written question, they will invest time into answering it.

Comment: this seems like it should loop infinitely for grades greater than 65:
`while (gradeValue != -1 && gradeValue > 65) document.write("<br>" + gradeValue + " pass</br>");`

Comment: I'm kind of regretting investing the time in reading this.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code, but noticed there's an extra `}` before the `if` statement. I recommend putting your code into [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ikehux/1/edit) and fixing those warnings.

Comment: @Kai Recursive?  Why would you need recursion here?

I think something got messed up with the formatting on edit.  We need a clean view at what's going on.  jsbin seems like a good solution.

Comment: @sachleen Ah - I assumed that was the closing `}` for the `while` but indeed it is not.

Comment: yeah i was blinded. i removed everything but the regrets. those are still in place.

Comment: @TimCarl Is there supposed to be an opening `{` on the while loop or does the loop only apply to the subsequent `document.write()`?  That extra `}` is a source of confusion - maybe lef from some code not posted here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think there should be an opening brace.. the code would make a lot more sense: prompt user to input grade until it's not `-1` (or failing, i guess)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need that much code.

I have updated your code, and it should work. Take a look at it.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDjA9/1/embedded/result/

```
var gradeCounter =0, gradeValue = 0, total = 0, average, grade;

//Loop
while (gradeValue != -1 && gradeValue <= 65) {

    //Prompt the user
    grade = prompt("enter grade, -1 to Quit:", "0");
    //Parse the prompt result to a int
    gradeValue = parseInt(grade);

    //Check if gradeValue is smaller than 0
    if(gradeValue < 0){
        //If it is, then we can finish adding grade
        document.write("<br>Finish adding grades");
    } else{
       //Add gradeValue to total score
       total += gradeValue;
       //Increment the number of grades by 1
       gradeCounter += 1;
       //Output to the user
       document.write("<br>" + gradeValue + " pass</br>");
   }
}

//Calculation
total = total + gradeValue;
average = total / gradeCounter;

//Output
document.write("<br>total grade: " + gradeCounter + "</bt>");
document.write("<br>average passing grade:" + average + "</br>");​
```